# Biblioteca com script mais leve para criar Gráficos de linhas

Tags: javascript

Estou com um pequeno problema ao criar gráficos line chart. Os ficheiro não podem ser externos e tem de ser locais. Preciso de utilizar uma biblioteca das mais leves possíveis. Já utilizei a graphael-min.js e a chart.js e são muito pesadas para o que preciso. Ou seja os script tem muitas linhas de código. O gráfico que quero é o mais simples possível. Alguém sabe qual posso utilizar?

Comment: Eu uso muito a d3.js, mas também é "pesada". Eu adaptei o [Flot charts](http://www.flotcharts.org/) para MooTools há uns tempos ([link](https://github.com/SergioCrisostomo/Mootools-chart-flot)), a versão original é com jQuery.

Comment: @Sergio muito porreiro, mas os ficheiros externos contém muitas linhas de código, como moo.flot.js o que torna esse ficheiro mais pesado. Não da para adaptar com menos linhas?

Comment: Podes fazer a tua própria :) Com só aquilo que precisas.

Comment: Um provável candidato à solucionar esse problema é o anychart [https://www.anychart.com/pt/](https://www.anychart.com/pt/)